# Divs disapear while animating fixed div

Tags: jquery, css

Here is a jsfiddle of what I'm trying to accomplish

http://jsfiddle.net/DF3t9/

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="top_bar">
    <div class="nav_column">
    </div
</div>
```

If you notice when you click on they yellow bar it shortens as expected but the green bar disappears during the animation. Is there a way to stop this from happening?

Answer (score 3):

Take nav_column out of top_bar, doesn't seem like there's a reason it should be in that div.

http://jsfiddle.net/DF3t9/4/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="top_bar">
    </div>
        <div class="nav_column">
        </div>   
</div>
```

Comment: Works perfectly, could you explain why it was disappearing before.

Comment: Not exactly, I tried setting overflow:visible and z-index changes but I would assume something to do with children elements when the parent's height changes via .animate()

Answer (score 3):

If you cannot change the markup you can add:

```
overflow:visible !important;
```

to the .top_bar class.

http://jsfiddle.net/DF3t9/5/

Comment: Upvote, I didn't think of using !important, I bet that .animate()'s inline styles on transition are messing it up.

Comment: Yup, I think that when an animate method is called it sets overflow:hidden; on the parent element.